# Xamarin.Forms Portable Class Library Project with Sharp.XMPP library

Tags: c#, android, xmpp, xamarin.forms, portable-class-library

an specific issue has occured in my project. I've found only one library for C# supporting Android (in Xamarin): [Sharp.XMPP](https://github.com/pgstath/Sharp.Xmpp), [NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Sharp.Xmpp/), but I have troubles with it. When I write some sample code in separated portable class library,  I get these errors:

```
Error 1: '.ctor' is not supported by the language
```

by the line

```
using (XmppClient client = new XmppClient(hostname, username, password))
            {
              ...
            }
```

Next:

```
Error 2: Metadata file '...\Project.Jabber.dll' could not be found  
Warnings 2-6: Reference to type 'System.Net.Security.RemoteCertificateValidationCallback' claims it is defined in 'c:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETPortable\v4.5\Profile\Profile78\System.dll', but it could not be found   c:\Users\Kliford\Downloads\S22.Xmpp\S22.Xmpp.dll
```

I am clueless.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Sharp.Xmpp` is not compatible with `PCL` since it uses the [XmlElement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlelement%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)  class, which is not currently available  in `PCL`.

Rewriting this part is doable, but requires a significant effort.

The workaround that I use, is to develop `.Net 4.5` Class libraries, which reference `Sharp.XMPP`. Portability among `Windows` and `.Net` is achieved through `Xamarin`.

Hope this helps

Comment: Ok, I finally set up the project with the library, thanks a lot, but after I connect, the error occured: host-unknown. Any idea?

Comment: Probably some DNS setup issue. Setting up the XMPP server needs some configuration. You can post a new question here or at github, I will be happy to help out if I can.

Comment: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32780463/host-unknown-exception-in-xmpp-xamarin-android) is the question. Thanks a lot, I really appreciate an effort.

Answer (score 0):

This also happens when a lower library is using a different version of the .NET Framework. 
You try to update de library at the same version of the .NET Framework that you use and it should work.